# Composer.Json use private respostory which has another composer.json file and have it run this after pulling repository

Tags: php, dependencies, package, composer-php

I am trying to use two composer.json in two different repositories.

First the composer.json on the root repo, is using this in the composer .json:

"repositories": [
{
"type": "vcs",
"url":  "my-sample-lib"
}
]

"require": {
"mylib/my-sample-lib": "dev-develop"
}

My question is, when I include this repo, this repo my-sample-lib also has its own composer.json file that I would like to have also run the composer update on automatically on when it is included, is that possible?

Currently I have to run composer update, then cd to /vendor/my-sample-lib/ and then do another composer update. Is there a way to make the first composer update run the second composer update automatically?

I read about package-path and this I set to ./ as this was on the top of the new repo, so this should have ran if I am not correct but yet it does not.

Comment: Why would you need to run `composer update ` on dependency (`my-sample-lib`)?

Comment: What happens if you do **not** run `composer update` in that vendor dir? There are a lot of libraries out there that do not need this extra step

Comment: The reason is that the repository is our own that has it's own composer.json inside it and has the dependencies that we use in that project, so we include this project as a dependency in other projects. Its a private repository we are including so we need a way to run that on this when it is installed.

Comment: the only way I can think of is to use the scripts directory to put in a command to cd into the directory and run composer install this way but there is no way to run it on the sub-libraries?

Comment: According to the way I was told this repository would work is other places would include it, and don't want their composer to have to include all that is needed in ours in order for it to run.